# How to set header jsp page fields from servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP, Servlet technology. I am working on a sample demo application using JSP, Servlets in which I am using a header.jsp file which I am including in many screens.

header.jsp have 8 fields and it's values should be set based on case number searched and retrieved details.

I searched over google to find a way to set values of header.jsp fields. But I didn't get a way. So finally I used session and I am setting fields in session which I want to display in header. I am initializing these fields each time a case is searched.

I know this is not a good practice. But I am not getting a proper way. Can someone suggest a good way for this?

header.jsp:

```
 <body>
<div style="background-color:#94BFA6;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width = "15%" class="label"> Case Name </td>
            <td width = "20%"> <% out.print( session.getAttribute("caseNumber") + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  " + session.getAttribute("caseName")); %> </td>
            <td width = "10%" class="label"> Magi </td>
            <td width = "15%"> <% out.print( session.getAttribute("magiSts")); %></td>
            <td width = "10%" class="label"> Language </td>
            <td width = "15%"> <% out.print( session.getAttribute("language")); %></td>
            <td width = "10%" class="label">Office Number</td>
            <td width = "15%"><% out.print( session.getAttribute("officeNumber")); %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Cash</td>
            <td><% out.print( session.getAttribute("cashSts")); %></td>
            <td class="label">Food Stamps</td>
            <td><% out.print( session.getAttribute("foodStampSts")); %></td>
            <td class="label">Medi-Cal</td>
            <td><% out.print( session.getAttribute("medicalSts")); %></td>
            <td class="label">File</td>
            <td><% out.print( session.getAttribute("file")); %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

And inside SearchServlet.java I am setting session variables:

```
public void initHeaderFields(String caseNum){

    if(!caseNum.isEmpty()){
        ArrayList<String> parms = new ArrayList<String>();
        parms.add("S");
        parms.add(caseNum);
        parms.add(getCurrentDate());

        ResultSet rs = conn.runStoredProc("DC001R",parms);
        try{
            if(rs.next()){
                session.setAttribute("caseNumber", rs.getString("CS_CSN_NUM").trim());
                session.setAttribute("caseName", rs.getString("CS_CASE_NAME").trim());
                session.setAttribute("language", getLanguage(rs.getString("CS_PRIM_LANG").trim()));
                session.setAttribute("officeNumber", rs.getString("CS_CASH_OFF_NUM").trim());
                session.setAttribute("magiSts", getAppStatus(rs.getString("CS_CC_STS").trim()));
                session.setAttribute("cashSts", getAppStatus(rs.getString("CS_CASH_STS").trim()));
                session.setAttribute("foodStampSts", getAppStatus(rs.getString("CS_FS_STS").trim()));
                session.setAttribute("medicalSts", getAppStatus(rs.getString("CS_MC_STS").trim()));
                session.setAttribute("file", getAppStatus(rs.getString("CS_CASH_FILE").trim()));
            }
            rs.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error while initializing header page");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data are not related to a session, but to a request is better to store them in the Request.

You need simply to replace the reference to the session with a reference to the request and it works (both, on the jsp and on the servlet too).

Additionally it can be useful to use instead of the following

```
<% out.print(session.getAttribute("magiSts")) %>
```

this equivalent code (I replaced session with request also)

```
<%= request.getAttribute("magiSts") %>
```

or

```
${magiSts}
```

Comment: But in this..every time I redirect to a page having header page included.... I have to set request fields right?

Comment: Right. If the data are common to each request of the session you can save them in the session without re initing them between requests.

Comment: I'm including header page in many other pages...so is there any way in which I can store the header fields in some globally accessible data structure?

Comment: Ohk. Means I can continue with my current approach right?

Comment: If the data never changes or if you re init the values in the session if they change yes. But is better to write the access to the variables in a different more efficient and readable form

Comment: Ok. Will try using your approach. Thanks for sharing information :)